# Axure: Is there a way to swap objects on mouse enter?

Tags: axure

Ive created dynamic objects which need to swap over on the mouse enter interaction; what is the best / easiest way to accomplish this?[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1E4h.png)

[image: image 2]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is an Axure support question, it isn't a UX question needing solving. It's better asked on the actual Axure forum.

Answer (score 3):

You can create 2 state of the dynamic object. Each state can have an image. [image]
Hope it helps you